# stop rotation of map through heading

Tags: ios6, mapkit, xcode4.5

I have rotated the map through didupdateheading. and setMKUserFollowWithHeading. Now if i move the device the user always points towards north. I want to stop the rotation of map through stop button to the position it had already rotated.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the angle about which the map has rotated by

```
heading = newHeading.trueHeading;
```

and transform the map in Stop button by implementing Stop button method as:

```
[mapView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(heading * M_PI /180.0f);
```